# Right click in UIKit for Mac

Tags: ios, uikitformac

I've got an iPad app that I ported to Mac really easily.

I'm using touch began / moved / ended, and it ports nice, tho I'd like to use right click on my iOS app on Mac.

How to register right clicks in a UIKit for Mac App?

Answer (score 5):

I don’t think you can add arbitrary right-click gestures, but if all you want is for a right-click to show a context menu, then the new [`UIContextMenuInteraction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontextmenuinteraction?language=objc) has got you covered:

```
let interaction = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
someView.addInteraction(interaction)
```

… and then implement the `UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate` methods to configure and show the context menu. On macOS, the “context menu interaction” is a right-click, and the context menu will appear as a standard macOS popup menu.

`UIContextMenuInteraction` is pretty low on documentation at the moment, so this blog post is helpful if you need it:
https://kylebashour.com/posts/ios-13-context-menus

Answer (score 3):

Building on Adam's answer, if all you want is to capture right clicks on a view the following will work:

```
class Bubble: UIView, UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate {
    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        addInteraction(UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self))
    }

// UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate ================================================================
    public func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        // Do Stuff
        return nil
    }
}
```